# Set value of textbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

My Jade template -

```
input#main_search.span2(
    style = 'height: 26px; width: 800px;' ,
    type = 'text',
    readonly='true',
    name='searchBar',
    value='test'
)
```

JS file -

```
$('#searchBar').val('hi')
console.log('sup')
```

Console output -

```
sup
```

But `searchBar` value stats at test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are logging `sup` directly which is a string

```
console.log('sup')
```

Also you are using the wrong id

The template says `#main_search` but you are using `#searchBar`

I suppose you are trying this out

```
$(function() {
   var sup = $('#main_search').val('hi')
   console.log(sup);  // sup is a variable here
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the right selector, and then wait until the page is ready and that the element exists until you run the function.

```
$(function(){
    $('#searchBar').val('hi')
});
```

As Derek points out, the ID is wrong as well.

Change to `$('#main_search')`

Answer (score 2):

1) you are calling it wrong way try:

```
$(input[name="searchBar"]).val('hi')
```

2) if it doesn't work call your .js file at the end of the page or trigger your function on document.ready event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(input[name="searchBar"]).val('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're targeting the wrong item with that jQuery selector. The `name` of your search bar is `searchBar`, not the `id`. What you want to use is `$('#main_search').val('hi')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#main_search').val('hi');
});
```